# Visual Studio - Tidy Up Variable Declarations

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any short cut in Visual Studio to tidy up Variable Declaration.

For example, I am working my way through writing a method, and because I am focusing more on the logic of the method than on tidiness I maybe declare the variables I think I need at the top, then a few more as I need them as I go on.

```
string myString, mySecondString;

myString = "Foo";
mySecondString = "Barr";

string forgotINeededThisOne = String.Format("{0} - {1}", myString, mySecondString);
```

Is there any way I can quickly do this:

```
string myString, mySecondString, forgotINeededThisOne;
```

Or do I need to do this manually?

Thanks

Comment: There is no built-in way to do this. It might be available via third-party add-ons.

Comment: Why? Personally, I find having variables declared close to where they will be used is more readable.

Comment: @Oded - Really? I was worrying that it would make my code look untidy/unprofessional but this is ok to do?

Comment: Sure. There is no universal rule that states "declare all variables at the top of the class/function".

Comment: @Oded: Isn't there such a rule imposed on C programs, i.e., declare all variables at the start of a block before any execution statements?

Comment: @ShaileshTainwala - Not as far as I know. Within a function, you should declare it _before_ you use it, but there is nothing that demands that you declare _all_ variables at the top of a function.